# Sending JSON Webhook Response

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra, httparty, zapier

I'm trying to receive a request from a webservice via JSON and send a successful response message back if the token is correct along with some other identifying information, otherwise send a proper error message

```
post "/hook/foo/bar" do
puts request.env

if request.env['TOKEN'] === "secret_code"
  HTTParty.post("https://hook.com/hooks/catch/foo/bar/",
  {
    :body => @info.to_json,
    :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept' => 'application/json'}
  })

  [200, {}, "Success"]
else
  [400, {}, "Authorization Failed"]
end
```

The service sending the hook (Zapier) says it sends successfully, but i'm not responding any meaningful data to them that I can use. I believe my formatting for my responses is wrong, but i'm not sure how.

Comment: not sure I understand correctly but are you expecting to return some of the response data from that POST request your making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David from the Zapier Platform team here.

Per the sinatra [docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html), you can return:

> An Array with three elements: [status (Fixnum), headers (Hash), response body (responds to #each)]

So you're sending back no hints on the content type and a string as the body. This is valid, and your hook succeeds, but you can do better!

Zapier parses the response from an outgoing hook as JSON, so it's best to send that back.

I've just tested the following example:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'

get '/' do
  'hello world!'
end

post '/hook' do
  {message: 'great!'}.to_json
end
```

and my response was parsed!
[image]

If you want to set a status code, honestly the easiest way to do it is with the function `status(400)` anytime before your return. That being said, a `401` is probably the code you want for `Unauthorized", rather than`400`. Either way though, zapier will flag that run as an error.

​Let me know if you've got any other questions!